# How do I get a form's select options text and values?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to scrape a form's `select` elements.

For example:

```
<select id="colors" name="colors">
  <option class="" value="1">Blue</option>
  <option class="" value="2">Green</option>
</select>
```

I would like `1 => 'Blue'`, `2 => 'Green'`, etc.

I tried using `at_css` and `xpath` but had no luck at all.

I guessed this would be the right track:

```
doc.at_css("#colors option").each do |d|
  puts d
end
```

Which just gives me one:

```
value
```

I can get every `option` text on the page using xpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
doc.css("#colors option").each do |d|
  puts d.attr("value")
  puts d.text
end
```

or as an object:

```
doc.css("#colors option").each_with_object({}) do |e,o| 
  o[e.attr("value")] = e.text
end
```

Comment: Aghhhh.  I was using at_css.  Just .css was the ticket.  I feel stupid now. Thank You

Comment: Fun functional-style: `map = Hash[ doc.css('#colors option').map{ |o| [o['value'], o.text] }]`